# Laravel 5.5 can't get selected column data using belongsTo

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have 2 models (`User` & `UsersDetails`) in relation with Eloquent Laravel.

**Model "User" Realation With 'SelDetails'**

```php
public function SelDetails {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UsersDetails', 'users_id');
}
```

**I want to get only two column 'created_by_id', 'created_by_name' from SelDetails**

UserController

```php
$users = User::with(['SelDetails' => function($query){
        $query->select(['created_by_id', 'created_by_name']);
    }])
    ->where('is_active', '=', 0)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

I am getting data from `User` but getting blank in `SelDetails`

```php
[relations:protected] => Array
(
     [SelDetails] => 
)
```

Please correct me.

Comment: add column user_id in select : ```$query->select(['user_id', 'created_by_id', 'created_by_name']);```

Comment: add created_by_id in relation : ```public function SelDetails {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UsersDetails', 'users_id', 'created_by_id');
}```

Comment: @Mohammad that's not working

Answer (score 2):

guys thanks for your precious response on this issue. i got the solution via following way.

**changes in "User" model Relation With 'SelDetails'**

```
public function SelDetails {
    #return $this->belongsTo('App\UsersDetails', 'users_id');// the old one
    return $this->hasOne('App\UsersDetails', 'users_id');
}
```

**changes in "UserController"**

```
$users = User::with('SelDetails')->where('is_active', '=', 0)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

that's the changes that I have made and got the result

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

`$users = App\Book::with('author:id,name')->get();` from [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)?
In your case it should looks like:

```
User::with('SelDetails:created_by_id,created_by_name')
    ->where('is_active', '=', 0)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

`with()` method can take string (or array filled by strings) eg. `relationName:column1,column2`.

Comment: This is the answer.  The documentation even describes exactly how to do this.

Comment: it's not working for me. thanks for your response. BTW I just found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it might be the array in select, try

```
$query->select('created_by_id', 'created_by_name');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response